# Windows authentication with permissions (from ldap?) for a Django web application

Tags: django, ldap, kerberos, django-login

I work for a company that has a number of web applications on the intranet. All of these apps are hosted on IIS servers and users who have access to these applications are auto logged in when they open these apps. I am writing a web application in Django which will be hosted on the intranet.

Now, I can do LDAP authentication with django-ldap to query the Microsoft AD service and log in specific users or I can use the "REMOTE_USER" value set by IIS to log in users using their Windows account (RemoteAuthentication backend). However, I can't seem to set permission and roles or restrict users using the RemoteAuthentication backend.

Is there any way to combine the above two? I would like my users to be auto logged in to the Django app using their windows account but only the users that should have access to the Django app and also set permissions.

Comment: AFAIK, frameworks which don't support SSO (Single Sign-On) with Active Directory are usually hidden behind a proxy _(e.g. Apache)_ which manages the authentication/authorisation against AD, then forwards the traffic with extra headers about user ID and groups.

Comment: In your case, the proxy could handle the messy Kerberos SPNego authentication and leave it to your app to accept or reject the user (based on which AD groups and/or app groups it belongs to).